# Sequence of solutions to a continuous ordinary differential equation in $\mathbb R^n$ has a convergent subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, equicontinuity, arzela-ascoli

How can I prove that a sequence of solutions to a continuous ordinary differential equation in $\mathbb R^n$ has a subsequence that converge to a limit ?

I was thinking of using Arzela Ascoli theorem. That is every uniformly bounded and equicontinuous sequence of functions in $C [a,b]$ has a convergent subsequence but got stuck in relating it. Can someone help?

Comment: Try to find a proof of Peano's theorem in your favourite ODE book.

Comment: For "nice" ODE, solutions are continuous in the initial values. This is usually proven using the Grönwall theorem. Only when that is not applicable do you need heavier techniques.